# emacs evil-mode simple bindings for command mode

Tags: emacs, evil-mode

In my ~/.vimrc I have had the following two keybindings to make getting into command mode easier for myself over the past fifteen years:

```
nmap ; :
vmap ; :
```

Is there an easy way to do this in emacs evil mode?

I have been reading through the wiki at http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Evil and haven't come across the correct way as of yet...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Binding a key to a command

The command that gets executed when you hit `:` is `evil-ex`, as you can find out by running:

```
:describe-key<CR>
:
```

(i.e. run Emacs' `describe-key` command, then hit the key you want info on).

So you can just bind `;` to also run `evil-ex`.

```
(define-key evil-normal-state-map (kbd ";") 'evil-ex)
(define-key evil-visual-state-map (kbd ";") 'evil-ex)
(define-key evil-motion-state-map (kbd ";") 'evil-ex)
```

### Binding one key sequence to another

In Emacs, just generally, you can define keyboard macros, which are basically the same as how Vim handles mappings:

```
(global-set-key (kbd ";") (kbd ":"))
```

In evil-mode, you need to add them to the relevant keymap for the state:

```
(define-key evil-normal-state-map (kbd ";") (kbd ":"))
(define-key evil-visual-state-map (kbd ";") (kbd ":"))
(define-key evil-motion-state-map (kbd ";") (kbd ":"))
```

**However**, for some reason that does bizarre things in this case. It's the first binding I've seen fail in that way. Just use the first version.

Comment: Thanks very much, i'll use the first case.  I had been getting bizarre behaviors and as a newcomer from vim I wasn't sure if it was me or my config.  Thanks again.